# Can't close activity

Tags: android, button, back

finish(); does not work when pressing the back button a seccond time, only Visible and Invisible functioning currently in press button once

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        final ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final ScrollView scrol = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        final LinearLayout layOut = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_View);
        videoview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        scrol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    } else {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);


}
```

Comment: Try overriding onBackPressed() and putting this code there

Comment: Cant't error...

Comment: What error are you getting? What are you trying to accomplish with the above code?

Comment: Hey............

Comment: If you are getting an error or if the application is crashing, please post the pogcat here..

Answer (score 0):

Can't build apk

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            final ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            final ScrollView scrol = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
            final LinearLayout layOut = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
            final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_View);
            videoview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scrol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);


    }
}
```

Comment: "Can't build apk" is not an error. Please provide more information.

Comment: finish (); already functioning when pressing the back button twice, I have found the code: D